# IPP linker errors on cygwin

Tags: c++, linker, cygwin, intel-ipp

I've built  a program that uses mkl and ipp that runs on mac and linux. I'm now building that program for Windows using cygwin and gcc, and can't get it to link.

The errors I'm getting are:

> Warning: .drectve
>   `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
>   ../../../bin/libMath.a(VectorUtility.cxx.o):VectorUtility.cxx:(.text+0x95):
>   undefined reference to`
>   _ippGetLibVersion'
>   ../../../bin/libMath.a(VectorUtility.cxx.o):VectorUtility.cxx:(.text+0x157):
>   undefined reference to
>   `_ippsWinHann_32f_I'

(and many more like that).

I'm using link path:

> /opt/intel/IPP/6.1.2.041/ia32/lib

and linking to the following:

> ippiemerged, ippimerged, ippmemerged, ippmmerged, ippsemerged, ippsmerged and ippcorel.

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

God IPP has to be the most annnoying thing to work out what libraries you need.  Intel just do not give any info.

I use the following libraries:

```
"ippsmerged.lib"
"ippsemerged.lib"
"ippscemerged.lib"
"ippsrmerged.lib"
"ippsremerged.lib"
"ippcorel.lib"
```

Comment: @Goz -- yeah, IPP doc is totally lacking. I tried your list and still no love.

Comment: Does it still give the same link errors? Because I can definitely use ippsWinHann_32f_I with those ...

Comment: @Goz -- are you using visual studio, or cygwin? If cygwin, can I see your makefile?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem with the evaluation version when linking statically. The solution was to link dynamically: static linking is not supported without commercial license.